# C# - How to specify generic type constraints for multiple level of inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: c#, generics

I have following class hierarchy

```
public class EntityBase<T> where T : EntityBase<T>
{
    //nothing interesting here
}

public class Benefit : EntityBase<Benefit>
{
    //again, nothing interesting here
}

public class SeasonTicketLoan : Benefit
{
    //nothing interesting here
}
```

Now I have got following interface

```
public interface IQuery<T> where T : EntityBase<T>
{
}
```

When I try to build following class I get compilation error

```
public class EmployeesQuery : IQuery<SeasonTicketLoan>
{
}
```

I get an error saying `SeasonTicketLoan` class does not satisfy the constraint.

Comment: Well no, because `SeasonTicketLoan` inherits (indirectly) from `EntityBase<Benefit>`, not `EntityBase<SeasonTicketLoan>`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Benefit` class also should have a generic type - so all parent classes have the **"ultimate"**/sealed type as their generic type. Only the "ultimate"/sealed types have no generic arguments. 

The result is that in all parent classes all way through to the root parent class the generic argument contains the type of the "ultimate"/sealed class and no errors arise.

```
public class EntityBase<T> where T : EntityBase<T>
{
    //nothing interesting here
}

public class Benefit<T> : EntityBase<T> where T : Benefit<T>
{
    //again, nothing interesting here
}

public sealed class SeasonTicketLoan : Benefit<SeasonTicketLoan>
{
    //nothing interesting here
}
```